# Using CanCan with Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, polymorphic-associations

I am struggling to use CanCan with my polymorphic associations.  It is breaking down when I try and load the polymorphic objects in my controller.

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :viewable
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now I have a controller that deals specifically with images assigned to a trip.

```
class TripImagesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :trip
  load_and_authorize_resource :image, through: :trip

  def index
  end
end
```

However, when I hit this index action I get the following error:

**Couldn't find Image with id= [WHERE "images"."viewable_id" = $1 AND "images"."viewable_type" = $2]**

I can see the query being executed in the Rails logs:

SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."viewable_id" = $1 AND "images"."viewable_type" = $2 AND "images"."id" = $3 LIMIT 1  [["viewable_id", 1], ["viewable_type", "Trip"], ["id", ""]]

So the select statement looks good, except that it's trying to find only a single image (even though I'm in an index action).  It's specifying an image id (which obviously does not exist in the route params) and it's also limiting the result to a single row.

This is using Rails 4.0.2 and CanCan 1.6.10.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Should it be `load_and_authorize_resource :images, through: :trip` in your controller? images, not image

Comment: Nope, that gives the exact same error